# Convert an analog voltage into digital and relay it in serial over a single wire

Tags: adc, serial

I have Engineering background but not Electrical. I am working on a project where I have to integrate a sensor which has an analog voltage output to a LoPy module for IoT applications. Another person is taking care of the LoPy module stuff but I do need to provide him the output in 8-bit digital serial form over a single connection so that it can act as an input to the module (I have been told that that's how the input is provided to the module). Is there a way to achieve this without using microcontrollers?

EDIT 1: I meant 2 wires. I understand that a ground wire would also be needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear, but it seems you have a analog voltage from a sensor, and need to send that information in 8 bit digital form to a module using whatever protocol that module requires.

The first thing to do is to get the specs for what exactly that protocol is.  That includes the low level electrical interface (IIC, SPI, UART, etc), and exactly how the bits are transmitted.  Only after you know that does it make sense to decide what you need between the analog voltage you are presented and the digital information you need to send.

Trying to avoid using a microcontroller for some strange reason is just plain silly.  That's quite obviously what this is going to take, at least without a ridiculous and cumbersome pile of hardware from the Pleistocene.  Many many micros are available that have integrated A/D converters, and integrated hardware to help send on the data digitally, like IIC, SPI, or UART peripherals.  The micro reads the A/D and sends on the data digitally.

The flexibility of a micro lets you do additional things that might be useful.  For example, you might want to apply a little low pass filtering on the digital values from the A/D.  It might also be useful to not just map the whole analog range to the 0-255 digital range.  You can trivially add a offset and apply a gain to map a part of the analog range to the digital range.  Non-linear mappings can also be done.

Again though, before you do anything else, get proper specs for the digital interface you must send to.

Note that "single connection" might not be possible.  If "connection" means ground and a signal wire, then that is doable, depending on what the digital interface is.  If you are thinking a single wire, then you need to re-think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I am trying to avoid microcontroller is that I don't have much experience with them and have only worked with Arduino before. I don't know how to select any particular microcontroller for this particular task. I assumed that there are some dedicated ICs which perform this task alone.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [datasheet](https://pycom.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/lopySpecsheetAugust2017.pdf) of LoPy it has "Analog channels: 8x12 bit ADCs" so it will read analog voltages without trouble.

Depending on your sensor, you may need some amplification, conditioning, etc, or maybe not. More info about the sensor?

And, you can't communicate over one wire. You need at least one wire and ground, so two wires (or a cable)...

Comment: The sensor output ranges between 0.45V to 1.5V.

Comment: OK, if the ADC has a 3.3V reference, you'll only use 0.55V out of that, but since it's a 12 bits ADC, you'll still get 9 bits. If this precision suits you, then no need to amplify. You may need a RC filter to protect against noise/ESD but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

There are [several](https://tessel.io/blog/108840925797/a-web-developers-guide-to-communication-protocols) approaches of serial data bus ( half-duplex) depending on number of slaves and bandwidth;  GPIO (1pin), SPI(3pin) , I2C, (2pin)

### [GPIO](https://tessel.io/blog/108840925797/a-web-developers-guide-to-communication-protocols#gpio)

Pros: Simple, Requires a single pin, can operate from 1.8 ~ 5V

Cons: Not good for sending complex data , slow ~ 1kbd, short haul

aka: bit banger

Needs signal conditioning, shielding , twisted pairs with power and ground if remote power needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy ADCs that implement 2-wire serial interfaces, among many others.

For example, [TI's site allows you to filter ADC parts by interface](http://www.ti.com/data-converters/adc-circuit/products.html), including UART and 12C.

You need to find out from your colleague what this '8-bit digital serial form' is. It could refer to any number of protocols. It could even refer to the AMC1304-Q1's odd but neat time-averaged 1-bit stream encoding. Its impossible to identify a part with any but the most generic capabilities (i.e. a microcontroller) without knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Could this just be a simple V/F converter? Something like the KA331 or the LM2907 converts your voltage into a frequency and at 0.3% accuracy is just better than 8 bits. You'll only need one signal line. Of course you'll need another line to power the far end and a ground.

Use the pulse count function of the ESP32 to determine the frequency.

You don't mention the frequency response that you require for analog voltage. The low operating frequency of the F/V means that your sensor voltage can't vary quickly.

There is a bit of code on Git (esp32-freqcount) that facilitates accurately measuring the frequency of square pulses on a GPIO using Pulse Counter, RMT and Interrupt.